# Converting to Fin Type in Coq

Tags: coq

Can anyone tell me why the following projection function in COQ doesn't work?

```
Require Import Vector.
Require Import Fin.

Definition Proj {n:nat}{p:nat}(x:t p+{(exists m : nat, n=p+m)}):=
match x with
inleft y => y
|_  => F1
end.
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:
In environment
n : nat
p : nat
x : t p + {(exists m : nat, n = p + m)}
e : exists m : nat, n = p + m
The term "F1" has type "t (S ?6 (* [n, p, x, e, e] *))"
 while it is expected to have type "t p".
```

On the other hand, using concrete values for p works fine:

```
Require Import Vector.
Require Import Fin.

Definition Proj {n:nat}(x:t 3 + {(exists m : nat, n=3+m)}):=
match x with
inleft y => y
|_  => F1
end.

Eval compute in  (Proj (of_nat 2 3))  = FS (FS F1): t 3.
```

Comment: What do you expect the return type to be? What should you get back when `p` is `O`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want `Proj` to return a value of type `t p`. That is impossible for `p = 0` (because `t 0` is the empty set), and that's why you cannot implement `Proj` for arbitrary `p`. If you extend you function to take a proof that `p` is not equal to `0`, then you can implement it as follows. Read [Adam's CPDT Chapter on Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.MoreDep.html) to understand what is going on here.

```
Definition Proj {n:nat} {p:nat} (x:t p+{(exists m : nat, n=p+m)}) : p <> 0 -> t p :=
  match x with
  | inleft y => fun _ => y
  | _  => match p with
          | 0 => fun h => False_rect _ (h eq_refl)
          | S _ => fun _ => F1
          end
  end.
```